# Is it possible to make flexbox work on iphone 4/iOS4 or provide a fallback?

Tags: ios, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I've been searching the web but keep coming up short, basically I need to make my flexbow grid rows work on iphone 4 but I can't seem to able to do so. Since the version of safari on iOS4 doesn't support the new flexbox syntax I provided a mix of the old and the new, which has been given as the solution from my searches. However this doesn't work for me:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
```

I've got a header with some elements which I need to be able to center, which I can when using flexbox:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <button class="center-y">Some button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please note that the `center-y` class isn't the issue here. I just added it for clarity on what I'm trying to achieve.

Is there something wrong in my solution, if not, can I provide some sort of fallback in order to get this to work?

I'm checking on iphone 4 via [browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com), so there might also be a bug in their service for all I know.

Comment: @Paulie_D The centering isn't the issue, it's because the container isn't getting it's height. I just added it for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox is compatible with [all versions of iOS](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/) but for [older you must use old -webkit syntax](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox); please note that anyway *iOS4 does not support Wrapping* even if old syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vertically aligned inline-blocks while still keeping responsiveness.  Important: whitespace is included for inline-block so make sure to remove it or comment it out.

```
<style>
    .vertical-middle {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: none;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 vertical-middle">
        <p>
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
            long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
        </p>
    </div><!--
    --><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 vertical-middle">
        <button>Some button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can, as long as you don't need a `flex-wrap`, which -`webkit-box` doesn't support. But in order for flexbox to work, you have to give a `flex-grow` of 1, or at least specify a flex `width`. With the old `-webkit-box` model flex-grow is expressed as: `-webkit-box-flex: 1;`

Once the flex-item (`.col-xs-12`) can grow, you can just center the button with `text-align`.
See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxvqnrj8/) for your example.

Flexbox Tip: A good way to write backward compatible flex CSS, is to use this helpful flexbox [code generator](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) with the "Generate legacy flexbox styles" checkbox enabled. That will auto generate the full CSS code with the equivalent to apply for the old "box-flex" 2009 spec.

You can also use this [flexiejs playground](http://flexiejs.com/playground/) to see and test what the old flexbox model supports. Any newer version of Safari, Chrome and Firefox or even Edge should all work with it as intended.